# Selected Java version 15 is not supported by SDK (maximum 14)

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, sdk, java-15

I have tried to create a new project using Spring Initializr in Intellij IDEA Ultimate, and I get this error message:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't replicate on "IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.2 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-202.7319.50"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the new project, the dialog windows gives you the option to add jdk. Add jdk15 location to the list and have it selected before you proceed to spring initalizer settings.

Else Goto `Project Structure` (CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S) in windows and add Jdk15.